# How to Evaluate Given Probability With Microsoft Bayesian Network Editor?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian-networks

I am working on Bayesian Networks and Microsoft has a tool for it: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/groups/adapt/msbnx/default.aspx

When I say evaluate to program it evaluates P(X). However I want to find given probabilities of sth. like P(X|Y) i.e.

How can I do it with Microsoft Bayesian Network Editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At Evaluate window right click on variable and assign it **Yes or No** so other probabilities refreshes given it.